# Finding the maximum sum that can be formed from a set, by partitioning it into two subset

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, np-complete, subset-sum

## Decription

Given a set of numbers S.

Find maximum sum such that

Sum(A<sub>1</sub>) = Sum(A<sub>2</sub>)

Where, A<sub>1</sub>⊂S and A<sub>2</sub>⊂S and A<sub>1</sub>⋂A<sub>2</sub>=∅

And Sum(X), is the sum of all elements within the set X.

## Approach

**Brute Force**

The easiest approach is:

```
print maximumSum(0,0,0)
def maximumSum(index,sum1,sum2):
  ans=0
  if sum1 == sum2:
    ans=sum1
  if index >= len(S):
    return ans
  m1=maximumSum(index+1,sum1+S[index],sum2)
  m2=maximumSum(index+1,sum1,sum2+S[index])
  m3=maximumSum(index+1,sum1,sum2)
  return max(m,m1,m2,m3)
```

Time Complexity:O(2<sup>N</sup>)
Space Complexity:O(1)

Is there a better approach than this?
Optional:
I would like to know whether the given problem is an NP-Complete problem or not.

Edit:

### Limits

1 <= Sum(S) <= 1000000
2 <= len(S) <= 100
Time Limit: 60sec(can vary depending upon language used)

Answer (score 1):

Yes It is NPC problem
[Partition Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem)

You can see the pseudo polynomial algorithm part if the sum of the set is small

Comment: I have added the limits for the problem, also the partitioning problem you suggested is to find one subset with the given sum, the question states that we require two distinct sets with the same sum.

Comment: Am I missing something or what? The first sentence of the page:
 "...the partition problem is the task of deciding whether a given multiset S of positive integers can be partitioned into two subsets S1 and S2 such that the sum of the numbers in S1 equals the sum of the numbers in S2.", two sets S1 & S2 where S1 = S2, is that not what you want?

Comment: Find **maximum** sum such that ,Sum(A1) = Sum(A2)

Comment: First, I think it is still NPC, or you can use same method to solve the partition problem? (Also it just sounds even harder than partition problem)  Second, if it is NPC, there won't be a O(N^3) or O(N^4) solution...The best I can think of is O(N^2 Sum(S)).  So what do you want, you want a O(N^3) solution or a proof that it is a NPC problem?

Comment: O(N^2 *Sum(S)) is also ok. I am trying to find a solution.